# Filter Box Plug in

Tags: javascript, ajax, next.js

I found a web site that is has a perfect filter box. dose any one know what is the name of that plug in?

web site address: https://simkhan.ir/

Answer (score 0):

It's programmed by React. You should search for Reactjs components.